# Set a binary number to input

Tags: verilog

So I have the input:

```
input x1,
input x2,
input x3,
input x4,
input x5,
input x6,
input x7,
input x8,
```

And a variable called

```
reg [6:0] set_Individual_bits =7'b0000000;
```

My question is, how can I get the inputs to take the places of the zeros?
For instance, how I thought it would work was

```
set_Individual_bits <= (x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8);
```

However this gives me a syntax error:

> "Near text ','; expecting")"

Answer (score 3):

You can use concatenation operator (`{}`) to achieve what you want:

```
set_Individual_bits <= {x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8};
```